# How to compare all the letters in for anagrams in Java

Tags: java, nested-loops

In the for loop i want to compare letter by letter in the first word to all of the letters in the second word. I thought about putting it into alphabetical order but i think that's against the rules.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Anagrams{

public static void main (String [ ] arg){

    Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    //ask for thingss...am i allowed to use scanner?

    System.out.println("enter the first word");
    String word1 = Scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    System.out .println("enter the second word");
    String word2 = Scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    //make into string builder

    StringBuilder ThisWord = new StringBuilder ("");
    ThisWord.append(word1);

    StringBuilder ThatWord = new StringBuilder ("");
    ThatWord.append(word2);

    //do the booleanssss

    boolean lnth = true;
    boolean found = false;

    //see if they the same length
    if(ThisWord.length() != ThatWord.length())
    {
        lnth = false;
        System.out.println("sorry sis, "+ThatWord+" and "+ThisWord+" not the same length");
    }
    else
    {
        outerloop:
        for (int i = 0; i < ThisWord.length(); i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; i < ThatWord.length(); i++)
            {
            found = false;

            if(ThisWord.charAt(i) == ThatWord){
                ThatWord.deleteCharAt(j);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(ThisWord+" and "+ThatWord+" not anagrams - letters do not match");
                found = false;
                break outerloop;
            }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Im sure there are probable other issues, but at a quick glance `if(ThisWord.charAt(i) == ThatWord){` should probably be `if(ThisWord.charAt(i) == ThatWord.charAt(j)){` since comparing a char to the whole word will likely always fail

Comment: so you have to find anagrams without sorting the characters in alphabetical order?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Quinn maybe writing `if(ThisWord.charAt(i).equals(ThatWord.charAt(j))){` would be even better

Comment: Also, deleting from `ThatWord` while iterating through it should produce `IndexOutOfBounds` exception in the worst case, or just missed characters in the better case

Answer (score 2):

Can we use something like this:

```
public class Anagrams
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(checkAnagram("abc","cba"));
        System.out.println(checkAnagram("abca","cba"));
        System.out.println(checkAnagram("abd","cba"));
        System.out.println(checkAnagram("otp","pot"));
        System.out.println(checkAnagram("poo","oop"));
    }

    private static boolean checkAnagram(String first, String second)
    {
        if(first.length()!=second.length())
            return false;
        int []  alphabet = new int [26];
        for(int i= 0;i< first.length();i++ )
        {
            alphabet[first.charAt( i ) - 97]++;
            alphabet[second.charAt( i ) - 97]++;
        }

        for(int i =0 ;i< alphabet.length;i++)
        {
            if(alphabet[i] % 2!=0)
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
        return  true;

    }
}
```

Comment: that's a really interesting solution

Comment: Thanks @LászlóStahorszki :)

Answer (score 1):

Few methods you can consider
Method 1 -
Sorting the strings via the alphabet and then comparing them.

Method 2-
Creating a helper array. For each character in the first string you 
would increment the value in the array[charValue] by 1. For each character in the 
second string you would decrements the value in the array[charValue]. 
If it is an anagram you would get an array that will be filled with zeros at the end.

Method 3-
iterating characters of the first string and removing the character from the second string when found. If str2.isEmpty () -> Anagram.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to assign prime numbers to the letters of the alphabet (let's say [these](https://miniwebtool.com/first-n-prime-numbers/?number=26), where the first column should be the characters in the alphabet and the other are the primes obviously). Put these in a `HashMap<Character, Integer>`. Let's call it `PRIME_MAP`. It should look like `a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> 5, ...`

You create 2 `for` cycles. In each, you iterate through `ThisWord` and `ThatWord` respectively.

You create a product from the letters of the words like so:

```
int thisWordProduct = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < ThisWord.length(); i++) {
    thisWordProcuct *= PRIME_MAP.get(thisWordProduct.charAt(i);
}
```

And similarly for the other.

If the 2 products are equal, the 2 words are anagrams.

This solution might be a bit more abstract then the others suggested, but this should be more optimal then nested loops

Answer (score 1):

1. The method László mentioned is the fastest. Pair the letters of the alphabet with prime numbers:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> alphabet = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    //assign prime numbers to alphabet
    alphabet.put('a', 1);
    alphabet.put('b', 2);
    alphabet.put('c', 3);
    alphabet.put('d', 5);
    alphabet.put('e', 7);
    alphabet.put('f', 11);
    alphabet.put('g', 13);
    alphabet.put('h', 17);
    alphabet.put('i', 19);
    alphabet.put('j', 23);
    alphabet.put('k', 29);
    alphabet.put('l', 31);
    alphabet.put('m', 37);
    alphabet.put('n', 41);
    alphabet.put('o', 43);
    alphabet.put('p', 47);
    alphabet.put('q', 53);
    alphabet.put('r', 59);
    alphabet.put('s', 61);
    alphabet.put('t', 67);
    alphabet.put('u', 71);
    alphabet.put('v', 73);
    alphabet.put('w', 79);
    alphabet.put('x', 83);
    alphabet.put('y', 89);
    alphabet.put('z', 97);
```

2. Loop through both strings and find the product of their letters. If the product is the same for both then the strings are anagrams. Here's the method:

```
public static boolean anagram(String str1, String str2) {
        if(str1.length() != str2.length())
            return false;
        
        int str1product = 1;
        int str2product = 1;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            str1product *= alphabet.get(str1.charAt(i));
            str2product *= alphabet.get(str2.charAt(i));
        }
        
        return (str1product == str2product);
}
```